# Remove part of name after regex

Tags: awk, sed, zsh, filenames, rename

I have a number of video files using a naming scheme like

some-words-SxxExx.extension

which is my preference. Unfortunately I have a lot of files in this format

some-words-SxxExx-words-I-want-to-remove.extension

I need to remove automagically remove everything after the Exx portion.

Comment: Should we assume the `xx` stand for something - like pairs of digits?

Comment: Do you have the `rename` script installed?

Comment: Yes, the xx stand for a pair of digits.

Comment: Yes, I do have perl rename installed

Comment: Lots of answers, and quickly I might add. I was up all night so I'm going to hit the sack for a bit. I'll be sure to close after I've made my choice. Thanks for all the great input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `x`'s are placeholders, `zmv` should be able to do that with 
 `zmv -nv '(*S??E??)*.ext' '$1.ext'`

```
% touch foo-S01E02-garbage.ext bar-S07E17-moregarbage.ext
% zmv -nv '(*S??E??)*.ext' '$1.ext'
mv -- bar-S07E17-moregarbage.ext bar-S07E17.ext
mv -- foo-S01E02-garbage.ext foo-S01E02.ext
```

You could also use `'(*S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9])*.ext'` to just match digits in place of `x`.

Or if you want to use `sed`:

```
for f in *.ext; do
    echo mv -n "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -e 's/\(S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]\).*\.ext/\1.ext/')"
done
```

or with the Perl `rename` command (which is apparently now called `file-rename` in Debian):

```
file-rename -n -v 's/(S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}).*\.ext/$1.ext/' *.ext
```

(Remove the `echo` from front of `mv` and the `-n` flags from `zmv` and `file-rename` to actually do the renames. `mv -n` on the other hand tells it to not overwrite existing files, this works at least in GNU `mv`.)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$ echo 'some-words-SxxExx-words-I-want-to-remove.extension' | sed 's/\(S..E..\)[^.]*/\1/'
some-words-SxxExx.extension
```

(although I expect a zsh aficionado would be able to do it more simply using shell substitution).

Comment: Yes, I do prefer zsh, but I'm no expert. I'm clinically depressed and my thought processes are slowed to about the speed of someone with a bad hangover. Not stupid, but I do have trouble retaining stuff. Oh, well - just another challenge.